# Real inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have to prove this inequality:

Let $p$ be a real number such that $p\geq 1$. For all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a constant $C_\epsilon >0$ such that for all nonnegative real numbers $a$, $b$, 
\begin{equation}
(a+b)^p \leq (1 + \epsilon)a^p + C_\epsilon b^p.
\end{equation}
Can someone help me? 
Thank you.

Comment: What about $p$? Is it given and real positive?

Comment: $p \ge 1$ real.

Comment: OK. I edited your question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. If $b=0$ then the inequality is trivial. If $b>0$ then
$$(a+b)^p \leq (1 + \epsilon)a^p + C_\epsilon b^p\Leftrightarrow
f(t) \leq C_\epsilon $$
where $t=a/b\geq 0$ and $f(t)=(t+1)^p -(1 + \epsilon)t^p$.

Note that $f$ is continuous in $[0,+\infty)$. What is $\lim_{t\to +\infty} f(t)$?

Comment: The limis is $- \infty$

Comment: Yes, this means that $f$ is upper bounded in $[0,+\infty)$ by some positive constant $C_{\epsilon}$. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much